# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ... detallesAccesorios.php on line 21

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, warnings

Alguien sabría explicarme con precisión, por qué me da este fallo en pantalla? Si descomento el or die del `'detallesAccesorios.php'` me dice:

> 'no database selected'

Quiero sacar unos unos datos de mi bd y no se que puede estar pasando. El `while` del método `getEnlaces()` no puedo descomentarlo, ya que daría aún mas errores y no mostraría mi enlace: 'mas información'. Me gustaría saber por qué da:

> "Warning: mysql_fetch_array()" en la linea 21 de
>   'detallesAccesorios.php'

**SQL:**

```
class SQL{ 
    private static function cargaDatos($sql){
        $pdo=array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES utf8");
        $conexion="mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tienda";
        $usuario='root';
        $pass='';     
        $root=new PDO($conexion,$usuario,$pass,$pdo);
        $resultado=null;
        if(isset($root)) 
            $resultado=$root->query($sql);
        return $resultado;       
    }
    public static function getEnlaces(){
            $query="select * from accesorios order by codigoAcc desc limit 5";
            $result=mysql_query($query);
            //while ($registro = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td width='300'><a href=detallesAccesorios.php?ref=".$registro['codigoAcc']." title='Ver la ficha completa'>Más información</a></td>

            </tr>
            <?php 
            //}

        }
}
```

**detallesAccesorios:**

```
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>Descripcion accesorio</TITLE>
</head>

<body>
<div align='center'>
<table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='600' bgcolor='#F6F6F6' bordercolor='#FFFFFF'>
<tr>
<td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'>CÓDIGO ACCESORIO</td>
<td width='150' style='font-weight: bold'>DESCRIPCIÓN</td>
</tr>

<?php
require_once ('include/SQL.php');
//$codigoAcc = $_GET['ref'];
//$query = "select * from accesorios where codigoAcc='$codigoAcc'";
$result = mysql_query("select * from accesorios where codigoAcc=".$_GET['ref']) /*or die(mysql_error())*/;

while ($registro=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<td width='150'>$codigoAcc</td>
              <td width='150'>".$registro['descripcionAcc']."</td>";
}
?>
   </table>  
</div>  
</body>  

</html>
```

Comment: La extension mysql de php está obsoleta y a partir de php 7 ha sido eliminada. Te recomendaría utilizar mysqli. Dicho esto, podrías mostrar el archivo SQL.php?.  Al parecer lo que está indicándote es que no has seleccionado la base de datos y es lógico que de error en `mysql_query` y en cualquier otra acción que quieras realizar.

Comment: De acuerdo intentaré emplear mysqli. Acabo de añadir la clase SQL.php a la pregunta.

Comment: Veo que estás utilizando PDO y mysql a la vez.. Por favor mira este [enlace](https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/1528-clase-para-gestionar-bases-de-datos-mysql-con-mysqli-y-php/). Te será de ayuda para crear una clase para gestionar lo básico en tu base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Te falta pasar el objeto que se crea cuando se levanta la instancia de la base de datos

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from accesorios where codigoAcc=".$_GET['ref'], $db)
```

Te falta la variable `$db` este nombre puede cambiar dependiendo cómo lo hayas registrado. Al parecer el código no es tuyo, por lo que te recomendaría indagaras cómo se llama el archivo que tiene la conexión. Encontrarás algo similar a esto

```
$db=  mysql_connect('localhost', 'usuario_mysql', 'contraseña_mysql');
mysql_select_db('base_de_datos_seleccionada', $db);
```

Ese archivo lo debes incluir en todos los códigos que requieran la conexión a la base de datos.

A propósito ¿Por qué sigues utilizando el controlador [mysql](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php)? Ya no se le da soporte de hace muchos años, por lo que tiene muchos huecos de seguridad.

Te recomiendo hacer la migración a los controladores [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysqli-connect.php) o [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.construct.php)